# IzPack - Checkbox actions/listener

Tags: izpack

I have defined an check box as part of the `<panels>` definition in `install-definition.xml`:

```
<field type="check" variable="typeCheckBox">
  <spec txt="Type Check box" id="check.1" true="on" false="off" set="false"/>
</field>
```

I would like to trigger an action whenever the check box is selected/unselected. Is it possible to define the checkbox action or listener as part of the checkbox definition?

## Note:

I can write a panel and set the action listener for the check box in the panel class name. But I would like to know how this work can be simplified by configuring in the install-definition itself.